# How can convert dynamic pdf to static pdf using PDFBox of Java

Tags: java, pdf, dynamic, pdfbox, livecycle

I created forms with Adobe LiveCycle Desiger. This way I can import XML data into a PDF template using iText. However, many PDF veiwers don't support these type of dynamic PDF files.

I'm looking for a solution to convert ("flatten") these dynamic forms (also known as XFA forms) to static PDFs using an PDFBox(open source Java library)

The solution I have so far, is to open the form in Adobe Reader and to "print to PDF". This creates a regular flat PDF, but it's a manual operation on the desktop. I want an automated solution on the server side.

Comment: i can find to that [PDFUtil](https://gist.github.com/jribble/beddf7620536939f88db) but there are not flatten to xfa forms

Comment: Pdfbox has no deep XFA support, especially no built-in XFA flattening feature. You can of course implement something like that building upon the Pdfbox low level methods but beware, that is far from trivial...

Comment: i had used the itext library.